# How do I tell MacVim to always use a certain syntax highlighting with a certain file type?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, markdown, macvim

I'm looking for something to add to my .vimrc that would tell MacVim to always use Markdown syntax highlighting with TXT files.

Currently, I can do this manually with `set filetype=markdown` but I have to do that every time I open a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can automatically set the filetype for particular file extensions using `autocmd`:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile  *.txt,*.TXT set filetype=markdown
```

Add this line to your `.vimrc`.

Type `:help autocmd` within vim for more details; see also: `:help autocmd-group`. See also: `:help filetype`.

Comment: Thanks. This _kind of_ works: It doesn't produce the same results as `set filetype=markdown` does though. I'll have to look into the `autocmd` help and see if that helps.

Comment: See the edit, I'd used a slightly different command; the edit may work better for you

Comment: Ahh, yes. That did the trick. I was wondering about that lack of `=` sign...

Thank you very much.

Comment: yeah my earlier command wasn't quite right (lack of coffee), see `:help setfiletype` for the difference; docs say `setfiletype` is used in a `filetype.vim` to avoid setting filetype twice.